# How to play the video from a parent div by clicking an image(using jquery)

Tags: jquery

When I click on the image under the `div` with class `videoCircle`, the video in the previous video tag should play.

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video class="video">
        <source src="videos/vidtut1.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <div class="videoCircle">
        <img src="img/circle-play.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the below:

```
$(".videoCircle img").click(function(){
    $(this).prev().prev().paused ?$(this).prev().prev().play() : $(this).prev().prev().pause();
});
```

But it gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prev(...).prev(...).pause is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `closest('.videoWrapper')` to get the common parent, then `find()` the `video` to play. Try this:

```
$(".videoCircle img").click(function() {
    var video = $(this).closest('.videoWrapper').find('video')[0];
    video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
});
```

Note that you need to call the HTML5 video methods (`paused`, `play` and `pause` in this example) on the native `video` element, not the jQuery object containing it, hence the `[0]` after the selector.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Just add the semicolon to the end of second line.  took me 20 minutes to figure out what was wrong...

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. Thanks @MasterCassim for fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

you can reach like that

```
$(".videoCircle img").click(function(){
   var video =  $(this).parent().parent().find($(".video")).get(0);
   console.log(video.paused);
});
```

[js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/e8yc7xby/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this above.

**Js**

```
$(function(){
$(".videoCircle img").click(function(){
   var videoelement= $(this).parent().parent().find(".video").get(0);
     videoelement.play();
});
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/9pbpm7xt/2/)